# Collection of all template contents

Tags: templates, mediawiki, wiki, semantic-mediawiki

in my media wiki for my organisation I want to create a List of all decisions made in the past with the corresponding result (Yes/No ..)

For this I created a new template, which highlights the decisions in our protocols and adds a Category with the decision question. (see the code below)

```
'''Decision:''' {{{Question}}}</br>
({{{Yes}}}/{{{No}}}/{{{abstention}}}) [Yes/No/No vote]
{{#ifexpr: {{{Yes}}}>{{{No}}}|[[Decision::{{{Question}}}::Yes| ]]|[[Decision::{{{Question}}}::No| ]]}}
```

But when I use `#ask` to get all the questions.

```
{#ask: [[Decision::+]]
|?Decision
}}
```

I cannot get it to work correctly. I want to display a table where each row has the Question and it's corresponding result (Yes/No) in one column. 
My current status is having the Question followed by `::Yes` or `::No` like 
`Do you like this question::Yes`

My goal for the result is

```
__________________________________
|Do you like this question | Yes |
__________________________________
```

Many thanks for your help in advance, I feel like the solution is really close but I just can't get what I want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your template is instantiated only once per page (each question has its own page), you should separate semantic properties like:

> '''Decision:''' {{{Question}}}
>
> ({{{Yes}}}/{{{No}}}/{{{abstention}}}) [Yes/No/No vote]
>
> {{#set:Has question={{{Question}}}|Has decision={{#ifexpr:
>   {{{Yes}}}>{{{No}}}|Yes|No}} }}

- `#set` parser function creates properties silently, which is better than the piped inline syntax you used.
- The whole point of semantic approach is to have... proper semantic. So here you have a question and a decision (yes or no), so the corresponding semantic properties should be `Has question` and `Has decision`.

Then the query will be:

> {{#ask:[[Has question::+]]
>
> |mainlabel=-
>
> |?Has question
>
> |?Has decision
>
> |format=table
>
> }}

If the starting assumption is not true (you have multiple template instances inside one page), you should turn to `#subobject` parser function to store your properties instead of `#set`, like this:

> {{#subobject:
>
> |Has question={{{Question}}}
>
> |Has decision={{#ifexpr:{{{Yes}}}>{{{No}}}|Yes|No}}
>
> }}

Query may remain the same.